# Can ZFS cascade?

Tags: zfs

Currently, I have a raidz1 pool made up of four 4TB drives and I would like to better understand my upgrade options (I have my data mirrored so I can rebuild). Is it possible to create two raid0 pools (two 4TB each) and then create a raidz1 pool with an 8TB drive? (motivation use existing drives)

For example, let:

- vdev01 = raidz0: 2x4TB
- vdev02 = raidz0: 2x4TB
- vdev03 = raidz1: 8TB + vdev01 + vdev02

where raidz0 is striped and raidz1 is single parity. If this is possible, please elaborate on the pros and cons. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, this one seems to answer my question.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513495/zfs-mirror-over-one-large-disk-and-a-raid0-of-two-small-disks?rq=1

Comment: See the part that starts with *Virtual devices cannot be nested* in the `zpool` man page.